# Oracle APEX -How to combine server side condition of "requet = expression1" and "exisits ( sql query return atleast one row)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I want to call validation when
query return at least one row like ( select 1 from table where id = 1 )
and
when request "add_data" is called

Don't know what to select here:

[image: condition in validation]

Answer (score 1):

The value of request can be accessed via the bind variable `REQUEST` . To tackle your specific problem you could add that to your condition of type 'Rows returned' like this:

```
   SELECT  1 
    FROM table 
    WHERE (
           id = 1 AND
           :REQUEST = 'add_data'
          )
```

If you're more a fan of pl/sql you could take the condition type 'PL/SQL Function Body' with code like this:

```
DECLARE
  l_dummy NUMBER;
BEGIN
  -- quit here if request value doesn't match
  IF :REQUEST != 'add_data' THEN
    RETURN false;
  END IF;
  -- check if we have rows in table.
  BEGIN
    SELECT 1
      INTO l_dummy
     WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from table where id = 1) 
  EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RETURN false;
  END;
  RETURN true;
END;
```

This is more code but you could find it easier to read which can be an advantage for maintenance later on.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood it, `add_data` request is related to a button you push. If that's so, then - if you don't do anything, request name equals button name - so let's pretend that button name is `ADD_DATA`. Therefore:

- in "When Button Pressed" property select button's name (`ADD_DATA`, right?)
- in "Condition Type" pick the condition you mentioned ("SQL query returns at least one row")